# Image is not showing on Pygame while using Sprite group

Tags: python, pygame

****blob image is not showing in the screen at the desired position, but it is showing at the top left of the screen . There are no error messages showing on the consol.
if you know the solution plaese let me know.****

---

blob image is not showing in the screen at the desired position, but it is showing at the top left of the screen . There are no error messages showing on the consol.
if you know the solution plaese let me know.
blob image is not showing in the screen at the desired position, but it is showing at the top left of the screen . There are no error messages showing on the consol.
if you know the solution plaese let me know.

My code:-

```
    import pygame
    from pygame.locals import *
    
    pygame.init()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    fps = 60
    
    screen_width = 700
    screen_height = 700
    
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Platformer')
    
    # load images
    sun_img = pygame.image.load("img/sun.png")
    bg_img = pygame.image.load("img/sky.png")
    
    # define game variables
    tile_size = 35
    
    
    # def draw_grid():
    #     for line in range(0, 20):
    #         pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 255, 255), (0, line * tile_size), (screen_width, line * tile_size))
    #         pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 255, 255), (line * tile_size, 0), (line * tile_size, screen_height))
    
    
    class Player:
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.images_right = []
            self.images_left = []
            self.index = 0
            self.counter = 0
            for num in range(1, 5):
                img_right = pygame.image.load(f'img/guy{num}.png')
                img_right = pygame.transform.scale(img_right, (28, 56))
                img_left = pygame.transform.flip(img_right, True, False)
                self.images_right.append(img_right)
                self.images_left.append(img_left)
            self.image = self.images_right[self.index]
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.x = x
            self.rect.y = y
            self.width = self.image.get_width()
            self.height = self.image.get_height()
            self.vel_y = 0
            self.jumped = False
            self.grounded = True
            self.direction = 0
    
        def update(self):
    
            dx = 0
            dy = 0
            walk_cool_down = 6
            # get key presses
            key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if key[pygame.K_SPACE] and self.jumped == False and self.grounded == True:
                self.vel_y = -10.5
                self.jumped = True
                self.grounded = False
            if not key[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                self.jumped = False
            if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                dx -= 5
                self.counter += 1
                self.direction = -1
            if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                dx += 5
                self.counter += 1
                self.direction = 1
            if not key[pygame.K_LEFT] and not key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                self.counter = 0
                self.index = 0
                if self.direction == 1:
                    self.image = self.images_right[self.index]
                if self.direction == -1:
                    self.image = self.images_left[self.index]
    
            # handle animation
            if self.counter > walk_cool_down:
                self.counter = 0
                self.index += 1
                if self.index >= len(self.images_right):
                    self.index = 0
                if self.direction == 1:
                    self.image = self.images_right[self.index]
                if self.direction == -1:
                    self.image = self.images_left[self.index]
    
            # add gravity
            self.vel_y += 0.7
            if self.vel_y > 10:
                self.vel_y = 10
            dy += self.vel_y
    
            # check for collision
            for tile in world.tile_list:
                # check for collision in x direction
                if tile[1].colliderect(self.rect.x + dx, self.rect.y, self.width, self.height):
                    dx = 0
                # check for collision in y direction
                if tile[1].colliderect(self.rect.x, self.rect.y + dy, self.width, self.height):
                    # check if below the ground i.e. jumping
                    if self.vel_y < 0:
                        dy = tile[1].bottom - self.rect.top
                        self.vel_y = 0
                    # check if above the ground i.e. falling
                    elif self.vel_y >= 0:
                        dy = tile[1].top - self.rect.bottom
                        self.grounded = True
    
            # update players coordinates
            self.rect.x += dx
            self.rect.y += dy
            if self.rect.bottom > screen_height:
                self.rect.bottom = screen_height
                dy = 0
    
            # calculate new player position
            # check collision at new position
            # adjust player position
            # draw player on the screen
            screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), self.rect, 2)
    
    
    class World:
        def __init__(self, data):
            self.tile_list = []
            # load images
            dirt_img = pygame.image.load('img/dirt.png')
            grass_img = pygame.image.load('img/grass.png')
    
            row_count = 0
            for row in data:
                col_count = 0
                for tile in row:
                    if tile == 1:
                        img = pygame.transform.scale(dirt_img, (tile_size, tile_size))
                        img_rect = img.get_rect()
                        img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                        img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                        tile = (img, img_rect)
                        self.tile_list.append(tile)
                    if tile == 2:
                        img = pygame.transform.scale(grass_img, (tile_size, tile_size))
                        img_rect = img.get_rect()
                        img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                        img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                        tile = (img, img_rect)
                        self.tile_list.append(tile)
                    if tile == 3:
                        blob = Enemy(col_count * tile_size, row_count * tile_size + 15)
                        blob_group.add(blob)
                    col_count += 1
                row_count += 1
    
        def draw(self):
            for tile in self.tile_list:
                screen.blit(tile[0], tile[1])
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), tile[1], 2)
    
    
    class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            self.image = pygame.image.load('img/blob.png')
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
    
    
    world_data = [
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 7, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    ]
    
    player = Player(100, screen_height - 91)
    
    blob_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
    world = World(world_data)
    run = True
    
    while run:
    
        clock.tick(fps)
    
        screen.blit(bg_img, (0, 0))
        screen.blit(sun_img, (70, 70))
    
        world.draw()
        blob_group.draw(screen)
    
        player.update()
    
        # draw_grid()
    
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
    
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()
```

Output :-
[Game screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fUJB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the location of the `rect` attribute, instead of separte `x` and `y` attributes.
Remove `self.x = x` and `self.y = y`

```py
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('img/blob.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        
        # DELETE
        # self.x = x
        # self.y = y

        # INSERT
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
```

or even shorter

```py
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('img/blob.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))
```

[`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) and [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update) are methods which are provided by `pygame.sprite.Group`.

The former delegates the to the `update` method of the contained [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) - you have to implement the method. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update):

> Calls the `update()` method on all Sprites in the Group [...]

The later uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects - you have to ensure that the `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s have the required attributes. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect`. [...]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is working fine now.